# GoogleAppEngine Datastore: returning keys to the user

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the best practice regarding returning keys of stored entities to the user?

In my case, I would like to have the user create entities and give it back to him their keys so that he is able to handle them in future.

For instance, my user should be able to create a `group`, providing group parameters. My system should return to him an automatically generated key.

I am now using

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
```

Is that the best practice?

What I should return to the user?
I saw that there is a `KeyFactory.keyToString` method that should return a string representation of the key, but it seems too informative to me.

A numeric identifier or a string would be sufficient for my purpose. I just want them to be auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you specify your entity `Key`, the keys are auto-generated and assigned values of type `long` from the datastore. In order to get this value, you execute `Long id = key.getId()` assuming that you have acquired the key from the entity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I didn't realize that the combination of type and `id` is enough without having to keep all the `Key` object.